# Making Swing components synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm reading *Java Threads* 3rd Ed. by Oaks and Wong (O'Reilly 2004).
They carry an example of a Swing typing game throughout the book.
The classes they define are mostly custom subclasses of `javax.swing.JComponent`.

What seems quite wrong to me is that they make those `JComponent`s thread safe with various synchronization methods.  I was under the impression that Swing components should not be thread safe, but rather that they should always be accessed from the Swing event dispatching thread. (Amusingly, one of the few times where they modify a component through the Swing EDT, it's for a `setText`, which is one of the very few Swing methods that do not need to be called from the EDT.)

I would like to know from some of you who have a lot of experience writing/reading Swing code:
Is it common for programmers to make Swing components synchronized instead of always modifying them through the EDT?  Is it tolerable?

**EDIT:**
I noticed it is nearly the same question as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643174/is-update-from-edt-in-swing-an-absolute-rule-or-are-there-exceptions).  However it does not say what programmers actually do in the wild.  I'm puzzled that an O'Reilly book would so blatantly violate the Swing threading model.

**EDIT:**
I discovered that they do briefly explain somewhere in the middle of the book the Swing threading model.  Nonetheless I'd like to have an answer to my question.  I have the feeling most who read this book will end up violating the Swing threading model since most of their examples do.

**EDIT:**
If you want to look at the code, you can [Download examples code](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007829/) as a zip file.  See for example ch03/example1/AnimatedCharacterDisplayCanvas.

**EDIT:**
I just learned that `setText` will not be thread-safe in Java7 (release in July 2011).

Comment: I always just make sure updates are done on the EDT.

Comment: You're wrong: `setText` **MUST** be called from the EDT!

Comment: @jfpoilpret It's thread safe according to the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html).  All `JTextDocument`s contain an inner `AbstractDocument` which has a write lock.  Whether you call `setText` from the EDT or not makes no difference since the lock has to be obtained.  (`getText` is not thread safe however.)

Comment: Thinking more about it: calling `setText` on the EDT is probably a bad idea since it could get stuck waiting for the document lock.

Comment: my mistake! You are right, thanks for pointing out this point, I felt sure that `setText` was like most all Swing methods. Now I don't understand why `JTextComponent` is implemented this way, maybe for historic reasons?

Comment: `setText` did not become unsafe in Java 7, it never was safe, contrary to the documentation. Java 7 fixed the documentation to reflect the reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivially, as long as the synchronized methods do not execute on the [`EventQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html), they won't block the event dispatch thread. Conversely, a method executing on another thread should *always* use the [`EventQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) to dispatch code via `invokeLater()`, `invokeAndWait()`, or a related mechanism such as [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) or [`javax.swing.SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). As a practical matter, these are reliable. The examples *may* be correct, but they should be examined from this perspective.

The [`EventQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) API says, "The only requirements are that 
events...are dispatched...in the same order as they are enqueued." In my opinion, this is tantamount to the "happens-before" relation of [`java.util.concurrent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) 
and the JLS. A more detailed discussion may be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.java.gui/sWKy5Oo8s3E/IqcnQ7Y6Sa0J).

Comment: In the book, they synchronize `paintComponent` since it accesses an object that is modified by some other threads.  They also synchronize the method that modifies this object.  I think what they do works; it's simply that it does not respect the Swing threading model.  If the example were to become more complicated, it could be a mess to maintain synchronization without having the GUI becoming sluggish (this is the reason why there are no multithreaded GUI's).

Comment: They do not use `invokeLater` and `invokeAndWait`.  For example, some thread generates a random char which is set as a member of a `JComponent` through a synchronized setter method of that component.  `paintComponent` of that component is also synchronized since it prints out the char member.

Comment: I guess my question in its simplest form is: Has anyone ever seen a synchronized `paintComponent`?

Comment: I gave you my answer 4 hours ago. Put updates on the EDT and forget about synchronizing! That is the whole point of the EDT and the single Thread rule. If you follow it you won't have problems. In all my years of posting on forums I have never once seen a suggestion by anybody to synchronize a painting method, or any other Swing method (that I can remember).

Comment: @camickr My question is whether real programmers sometimes sneak around this rule.  I would guess not.  But they do so in an O'Reilly book, which leaves me quite puzzled.

Comment: I defer to @camickr's greater experience, and synchronized painting is unfamiliar to me, too. I can see how _liveness_ would suffer. For reference, there's a summary of related idiom's [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/threadwatch). As an aside, I've used [protected types](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p1-2.html#9) in Ada to synchronize access to the Carbon API in the way you describe, but I'd build an EDT equivalent if I had to do it over.

Answer (score 2):

You should never have synchronized blocks on Swing components, its going to cause weird problems when its trying to be rendered.

Swing is not thread safe because everything is supposed to be updated on the EDT, even creation of Swing components.

Long running processes should be moved to a background thread or a SwingWorker. When a thread other than the EDT needs to make components or make updates to a component it should be wrapped using SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Comment: About your first paragraph: Yes, if the Swing EDT is waiting for a lock, the whole GUI will be locked up.  However, for the simple examples in the book, I don't think it was an issue (I did not try to run the code).

Comment: there's still no reason for a swing component to ever hold a lock. since its single threaded (the EDT) race conditions are not possible. It is OK to have locks on classes in a Swing application, but they should not be called from the EDT

Answer (score -1):

"Swing components are not inherently thread safe, and as a general rule, after Swing components have been made visible on the screen, you can only safely modify their data from the event thread. If you modify Swing component data from any thread other than the event dispatching thread, you must take precautions to ensure data integrity. An exception to this rule is the setText method on a JTextComponent or any of its subclasses, or any Swing component method whose documentation explicitly states it is thread safe."
 Monica Pawlan
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Threads/swing/

Comment: -1 The quoted article is outdated (2001). Sun has recently (2009 or 2010) made the thread-safety statement much more general: even component creation has to be done in the EDT.

Comment: Yep but the book was published before that in 2004 and the answer was for that specific case