# Using Event Queue to execute a simple method in main()

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, invokelater

I am working on a Java application that was developed by some guy as part of a research project. Following is the main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // Change the name of the application on a mac
                System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name",
                        "XX");

                // Use the top of the screen for the menu on a mac
                if( System.getProperty( "mrj.version" ) != null ) {
                    System.setProperty( "apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true" );
                }

                try {
                    // Use system look and feel
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Cannot use system's look and feel; using Java's default instead");
                }

                // Create a new instance of XX
                XX.getInstance();
            }
        });

    }
```

Now, I do not understand why was an event queue used instead of just using

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        //the MAC stuff!!

        XX.getInstance();        //this line creates the UI and the event handlers
    }
```

Is there any significance of using the **EventQueue**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties should be set on the [*Initial Thread*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), and the GUI should then be scheduled for construction on the *event dispatch thread*. Alternative approaches are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Change the name of the application on a mac
    System.setProperty(
        "com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "XX");
    // Use the top of the screen for the menu on a mac
    if (System.getProperty("mrj.version") != null) {
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Create a new instance of XX
            XX.getInstance();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`EventQueue.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) will run that Runnable on the GUI thread (dispatch thread).  You need to run updates to the GUI from the dispatch thread.  From your code here though, I don't think you really need it, you will only need to use it when you are running in a background thread (e.g. In a callback from an event).

Answer (score 2):

Swing (and, if we were being honest, AWT) are thread-hostile. Like the vast majority of GUI libraries, it isn't thread-safe and doesn't make sense for it to be - microsynchronisation isn't realistic. Worse it uses effectively mutable statics (actually uses a bizarre `AppContext` idea) to run work on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). This can occur even when setting up the GUI before "realisation".

Probably it wont be a problem. Perhaps in some cases, perhaps after a JRE update, it'll give some problems. Perhaps it'll just be a caret out of place. The question is, do you want to even have to think about risking that, or just slap in the standard Java-style verbose boilerplate?

Comment: +1 Violations are hard to diagnose, but easy to prevent; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3643174/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6445143/230513).